# Process HTML form values and output results to text files

Tags: php

Usually I can find solutions to similar problems online to come up with a solution to my own problem but the more I think about/research this, the more confused I get!

Happy to try & piece together my own solution (and post here for review/reference) but would appreciate some guidance on how to approach.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

From a simple HTML form containing the following fields:

- Start No.
- End No.
- Start Letter
- End Letter

pass the submitted information to a PHP script for processing.

Example values for the HTML form:

- Start No. = 0
- End No. = 3
- Start Letter = A
- End Letter = D

By entering only start and end numbers/letters the script would ascertain that in addition all values in-between those submitted are required for further processing steps/output i.e. 1,2 & B,C. I am assuming this information would be stored within either a single array or multiple arrays.

If all I wanted to do with the stored array(s) information was output a single text file with all possible letter+number combinations that looked similar to:

```
A0 A1 A2 A3
B0 B1 B2 B3
C0 C1 C2 C3
D0 D1 D2 D3
```

then that would be the end of my question and perhaps the first thing to try to achieve however what I require is the data to be split into 4 separate files as below:

files:

File1.txt

```
A0 B0 C0 D0
```

File2.txt

```
A1 B1 C1 D1
```

File3.txt

```
A2 B2 C2 D2
```

File4.txt

```
A3 B3 C3 D3
```

**Breaking my question down into steps:**

1. By submitting only start/end numbers/letters how can I ascertain the letters/numbers in-between (range)?

Answer: Use

```
range()
```

2. How can I then establish all possible letter+number combinations?

*No longer think I need to do but would involve merging arrays*

3. How can I then group by number value and output?

*Handled by foreach function*

**Update:**

My code below produces the first output file.

File1.txt

```
A0
B0
C0
D0
```

You will notice in the foreach function I am specifically asking for the first value of $array2. How can I instead repeat/loop the foreach and echo function for every value stored in $array2? (I know I will also need to modify further to ensure the text files created have unique filenames.)

```
<?php

//Example form values
$start_number = 0;
$end_number = 3;
$start_letter = 'A';
$end_letter = 'D';

//Letters array
$array1 = range($start_letter, $end_letter,1);

//Numbers array
$array2 = range($start_number, $end_number,1);

foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $string .= $value . $array2[0] . "\n";
}

echo file_put_contents("File1.txt",$string);

?>
```

**Working Example:**

```
<?php

//Example passed form values 
$start_number = 0;
$end_number = 8;
$start_letter = 'A';
$end_letter = 'D';

//Numbers array
$array1 = range($start_number, $end_number,1);

//Letters array
$array2 = range($start_letter, $end_letter,1);

foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {

    $string = implode($array2, $value . "\n") . $value;   

    echo file_put_contents($value . ".txt",$string);
}

?>
```

I am not convinced this is the best solution by using implode() but it works for my requirements, maybe somebody may find this post useful. Please do suggest improvements.

Comment: You might want to rephrase this question. It doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Hi chris85, I have tried as suggested.

Comment: It is clearer but too broad for SO.

Comment: I have included a semi-working code example in relation to my original question. This might make things clearer on what I was hoping to achieve. My question now is more specifically related to looping through arrays. Please suggest if I should ask as a new question (if I am unable to work out myself after further research).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

//Example passed form values 
$start_number = 0;
$end_number = 8;
$start_letter = 'A';
$end_letter = 'D';

//Numbers array
$array1 = range($start_number, $end_number,1);

//Letters array
$array2 = range($start_letter, $end_letter,1);

foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {

    $string = implode($array2, $value . "\n") . $value;   

    echo file_put_contents($value . ".txt",$string);
}

?>
```